# SharePoint New/Edit Form Separator

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column

I would like to have some headlines/separators between columns in the New/Edit form in a SharePoint List. Basically, I would like to have a separator in between the categories to which the columns apply. I attached a picture with a structure of what I would like to achieve. Anyone has any thoughts/experience on how this can be achieved?

[image]

Comment: OP wants (at least as far as I understood the question) to group fields together by arbitrary categories in the New and Edit forms of the list.  In his image, his list has seven fields.  He has them split into three categories.  The New/Edit form should group those fields by category, separated from each other and headlined.  I hope this helps whoever thought the question was unclear.  OP, let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. I've seen many examples of this being done in InfoPath, but I have no experience with it, so I was wondering if it can be done in another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create custom forms for your requirement. The most popular ways to create custom forms are:

**SharePoint Designer:**

Creating a custom form in SharePoint Designer is relatively easy. You take an existing SharePoint list and use Designer to create a new .aspx page which renders and controls the form. There are files used by a list to create forms, one each to add, edit and view. These are located in the same folder as their associated SharePoint list. With Designer you can show or hide fields based on certain criteria, change the layout, use various types of data controls, add rich text and graphics, and if needed work with the code used by the form.

Refer this [article for more information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23955.sharepoint-2013-building-custom-forms.aspx).

**InfoPath**

InfoPath is Microsoft's dedicated form creation and editing tool. With little or no coding, you can use it to build complex forms that can access many data sources to add, edit and delete. You can create multiple views within a form and choose which one is displayed when the form is opened. InfoPath requires Forms Services though, which only comes with SharePoint Enterprise. If you are using the Standard edition or WSS you need to upgrade or purchase the separate Forms Server product.

Unlike SharePoint Designer, InfoPath is only a forms editing tool and does not provide additional web page editing features. It's not very intuitive to use and you are limited to the functionality it offers, which covers most business needs though.

InfoPath works well with structured data, and can handle large text fields, calculations, business logic, and integrated workflows. You can only edit one item at a time though.

**Visual Studio:**

Visual Studio is Microsoft's integrated development environment and can be used to develop anything, from Windows Mobile apps to websites. It is a software developers tool and is well beyond the reach of a non-programmer. Like SharePoint Designer, it can be used to extend the functionality and layout of SharePoint's default list forms, plus it can be used to extend InfoPath solutions.

The sky is the limit though when it comes to possibilities. Any limitations you've encountered with other form tools can be addressed with Visual Studio. A skilled software developer will be able to create any functionality you have seen on any website or application.

**For other alternatives refer below article:**

Reference:[Seven Ways to Create a Form in SharePoint](http://go.limeleap.com/community/bid/286331/Forms-in-SharePoint-Seven-Ways-to-Create-a-Form-in-SharePoint)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable using SharePoint Designer. Create a custom form New and Edit which is available on a click of button. then arrange your fields under a group as you like and provide label with the heading. 
Download SP Designer.. its very simple.