# Resizing the Rich Text Editor

Tags: sharepoint-online, richhtmlfield, ie

Hopefully this is a simple question, as I'm new to Sharepoint.

When I'm editing an item in a list some of the fields have a Rich Text Editor.
How do I make the editor bigger, as it only shows a tiny part of the text I need to edit? 
I'm using IE11 with the Sharepoint in Office 365.

Also, is there a way to change the default size of the editor, so that it is always a bigger size?

Many Thanks.

Comment: This answer [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/167807/20615) details ways to create custom forms.  You will be able to set the size of your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online I was able to target the .ms-rtestate-field class to change the width of the multi line of text field.  I added a content editor web part above the form, edited the source and input the below styling.

```
  <style> 
  .ms-rtestate-field {
    width: 600px;
  }
  </style>
```

EDIT: You may want to use a script editor web part instead of a content editor.  I did notice when increasing the height that this made the content editor web part grow as well as it must be using the same class, which put a large gap at the top of the form.